# Black Screen after system update Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia

Hi bro I have a problem with my Ubuntu 13.10 after system update. My Ubuntu was black screen and there is a X cursor on my display.
My Gear
Intel Core i3 2310M,
2 GB of RAM,
Nvidia Geforce GT 520M,
500GB HDD.

[image]

How to fix that problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

type control + alt + F1
see if you could login in the shell.
you can look at logs and ckeck if any problems occurs.

if you don`t know how.
type

```
dmesg
```

or

```
dmesg | more
```

or try to repair the packages

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

I recommand to backup the /home folder and reinstall the ubuntu,you will waste tons of time repairing the packages.